# Persist a Java instance of an Interface in a database

Tags: java, postgresql, serialization, persistence

I would like to persist an object in a relational database (PostgreSQL). I don't know the specific class of the object to be persisted, I just know that it implements an interface.

What would be the best way to do that?

I was thinking to do something like:

```
Interface obj = new InterfaceImpl();
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
oos.writeObject(obj);
oos.close();
byte[] rawData = buffer.toByteArray();

String base64String = Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);
//Persist the string to DB


//Load string from db
byte[] backToBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(base64String);
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
Interface obj = (Interface) is.readObject();
```

Any better solution?

Comment: Basic Java serialization like you're doing is probably the best you can do if you don't know anything more about the type of the object and its true implementation.

Comment: Maybe a `bytea` data type instead of text (which I guess you are going to use as base64 encoding suggest) would be better solution for you. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-binary.html for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's really all you know about the object, then all you can really do is store it in a `bytea` field and retrieve it again later when needed.

Use `bytea` not `text`. It's faster for binary data (no collations or natural language support) and it supports storing zero (null) bytes, unlike `text`.

This should be an absolute last resort way to store data in a DB. It *always* leads to pain. Someone will come along and ask "ok, now write a query where you find all objects of type `com.mycompany.Apple` with their `colour` property set to `"red"`. You will have to reply "sorry, I can't do that, the database just sees a pile of binary gibberish". You will be told *"Do it anyway"*. So you read *every* object out of the database, deserialize it, check its type, check its properties by reflection and discard it or keep it based on the result. The database gets bigger and this gets slower and slower. So you start adding columns to cache information about the objects in the DB, but then they start getting out of sync with the stored data because some code forgets to update them...

I've written queries that poke around in `bytea` strings to manually deserialize and examine parts of Java objects before. Horrible stuff. Do not recommend.

If you can possibly do so, use a more practical serialisation of the object structure, like `json`. Something you can query in a practical manner from the database when you are inevitably asked to do so.

Comment: I can get the class of the object that implements the interface, that is known at runtime, and add it to another column. What do you think?

Comment: @mat_boy Still horrible - it should be your last resort. But it'll work.